# Cant create a vue project with CLI

Tags: vue.js, installation

This is probably because of my minor knowledge on terminal commands and filesystem on Mac OS but I have a really hard time to install a vuejs project.

First I tried to install with WebStorm 2018.1 and with the template for vue projects. I got on error pointing to permission problems.

After that I tried to install with vue init webpack (and sudo -i -u xxx vue init webpack) but got the error -
Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/webpack: EPERM: operation not permitted, utime

After that I tried to install with sudo vue init webpack which installed all the files but with root user and I cant edit the files when I am logged in as a user (admin), the files are read only.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: how did you install node.js/vue-cli and what version do you have? Run `node -v` `npm -v` `vue -V`.

Comment: Given that your first impulse was to `sudo` stuff, I'd bet you've previously attempted this "fix" for other issues and borked permissions all over. It should usually give you a file location that it failed on - you'll need to fix its perms.

Comment: ceejayoz you are probably right. I tried to rerun npm install --global vue-cli and got EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vue-cli/node_modules/cli-spinners' and npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.  And probably I used sudo because I earlier used sudo for node so I am stuck and I probably dont have the knowledge to uninstal everything (node, npm, vue-cli) and if I had. Maybe the OS will order me to use sudo anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why but it works.

I removed the hidden folder vue-templates (under my user account)

Installed the cli again with sudo npm install -g vue-cli. I thought that I should have problem again because I used sudo, but not.

And then I was able to use vue init webpack voutest without sudo an all the files was editable and not readonly as before.

I also updated npm to 5.8.0

Answer (score 4):

Please follow these commands:

To install the Vue CLI globally on your local system:

`npm install -g vue-cli`

To initiate a project

`vue init webpack vueapp01`

`cd vueapp01`

Start installing the dependencies by using npm again:

`npm install`

After having completed the installation of packages you can start the web server in development mode by using npm in the following way:

`npm run dev`

This will start the server on `port 8080` and the application output is displayed in the browser automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I run vue init webpack vueapp01 i got error - vue-cli · Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/webpack: EPERM: operation not permitted, utime '/Users/xxx/.vue-templates/webpack/.circleci'

Comment: Is `npm install -g vue-cli` successfully executed before you run `vue init webpack vueapp01`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, the node version was 8.0. I upgraded to 10.0 and it worked.

1. I removed all the node modules.
2. Removed node 8.x and npm.
3. Installed node 10.x and npm
4. Install @vue/cli using the npm.

Comment: I am using node 10.14 and npm 6.4 .. but still I am not able to move further and setup is stuck at project description .